# Copy file from real home into DynamicUser home

Tags: linux, security, systemd, x11, namespaces

I am working on restricting the permssions of user units in SystemD. One of the things that I want to do is set `ProtectHome=yes` (or `DynamicUser=yes`), but the process needs access to the .Xauthority file (as it needs to communicate with X). I attempted to use `BindReadOnlyPaths=$HOME/.Xauthority` but that does not appear to work, probably because it is a file, and not a directory. I suspect that the way I will have to do it, is copying the .Xauthority file into the created tmpfs, but I could not find a suitable way to do this. How would I go about doing this?